# Split string into segments using python

Tags: python, split

I am trying to come up with a code that is able to take in a string and split it into messages with n number of characters. Each message cannot exceed n but can have less than n characters as words should not be split. For example 'This is an example message' and n=10. This code would return 
'This is an'
'example'
'message'

Any suggestions on how I can approach this?

```
import math 

def solution(S, K):
    x = math.ceil(len(S)/K)
    y = S.split()

    lists = [[] for i in range(x)]

    for i in lists:
        while len(i) <= K:
            i.append(y[b])
            b+=1
```

x is the number of messages that I think is needed. Can someone explain to me how I can complete my code?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what the [textwrap](https://docs.python.org/3/library/textwrap.html) library is for.

```
>>> from textwrap import wrap
>>> print(wrap('This is an example message', 10))
['This is an', 'example', 'message']
```